# multiple services trying to connect to the same db container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  producer:
    build:
      context: ./producer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.producer
      target: prod
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    env_file:
      - ./producer/producer.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - network-db

  cleanup:
    build:
      context: ./cleanup
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.cleanup
      target: prod
    ports:
      - 4040:4040
    env_file:
      - ./cleanup/cleanup.env
    depends_on:
      - producer
    networks:
      - network-db

  db:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - network-db
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres-data:

networks:
  network-db:
    driver: bridge
```

And in both of the `producer` and `cleanup` services' codebase, I try to connect to the same port, which is 5432, like so:

```
configData := fmt.Sprintf("postgres://%v:%v@%v:%v/%v?sslmode=disable",
    pgUser,
    pgPassword,
    pgHost,
    pgPort, // 5432
    pgName,
)

GDB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(configData), &gorm.Config{})
```

At the moment I get a `connection refused` error and I am assuming it is something to do with the port.
So my question is, can `db` image handle connections from multiple services on the same port (5432). If not, then what is the better way to solve the problem?

Btw, `.env` files should not be the source of the issue since they match.. (port=5432, host=db, etc.)

Comment: You only have one postgres on port 5432, it shouldn't be a problem for different services to connect to it. The problem might be with the network or some configuration of the postgres itself (check `pg_hba.conf`). If you run them in `network_mode: host` then is it still a problem to connect?

Comment: If you dump out the `configData` string, does it look like what you expect?  There's a potential startup-time race condition that's especially visible with compiled languages where it's possible for the application to start before the database is ready; if you run `docker-compose up` without a `-d` option, do you see database startup messages appear after the client containers fail?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I have already tried to solve the race condition issue with solutions like wait-for-it.sh and sleep-and-retry while connecting in the codebase. but still no success. btw, configData seems ok..